# C4100 "Unreferenced Formal Parameter" when used in a Template

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-warnings, visual-c++-2012

This seems so simple that it shouldn't be a problem, but I'm not seeing it, so any help would be appreciated.

I have a function that takes a parameter, then uses that parameter in a template.  The compiler (Visual C++ 2012) is generating a C4100 "Unreferenced Formal Parameter" warning...and this is annoying.  I cannot see why it thinks the parameter is unreferenced.

```
#define FactoryRegister(f, T) \
{ \
    shared_ptr<FactoryCreator<T>> creator(new FactoryCreator<T>()); \
    f.instance().Register(#T, creator); \
    f.instance().Register(typeid(T).name(), creator); \
}

void FactoryRegister(hive::Factory& factory)
{
    FactoryRegister(factory, MyClass);
}
```

Compiling this generates: "warning C4100: 'factory' : unreferenced formal parameter"

I would have thought that "factory" is quite obviously referenced as its "instance()" function is called twice after macro expansion.  I assume here that the code expands to:

```
void FactoryRegister(Factory& factory)
{
    shared_ptr<FactoryCreator<MyClass>> creator(new FactoryCreator<MyClass>());
    factory.instance().Register("MyClass", creator);
    factory.instance().Register(typeid(MyClass).name(), creator);
}
```

The code functions fine, its just throwing a warning that I don't understand.  Note that, in my actual code, the macro and the function are in different projects and different files, but they were included here together for simplicity.

Comment: You know that could just be an inline function, right?

Comment: @DeadMG: I guess he wants to avoid repeating the type name (`#T`)...

Comment: I know inline could be suggested from what I've shown, but the functions are simplified here for the example.  The real functions are not candidates for inlining.

Comment: He's repeating it anyway.

Comment: @DeadMG: if that was an inline function he would have to repeat it twice: once as a type name, once as a string. am I mistaken?

Comment: Andy - Exactly.  The purpose of the macro was to get the string expansion and the class name at the same time, reduce the opportunity for error, and ensure that they are identical at compile time.

Comment: @JohnFarrier: it looks like a compiler bug to me, I see nothing wrong with your code. Maybe you could suppress the warning just around that function?

Comment: @JohnFarrier: or use a macro like UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(factory) just at the beginning of the function

Comment: I could suppress the warning, yes...but I tend to assume the compiler is smarter than me...and that I have probably done something wrong or do not understand something about the way it is expanding the macro.

Comment: @AndyProwl: "UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(factory)" would certainly fix it, but it don't see why I would have to use it.  From what I can see, "factory" is referenced.

Comment: @JohnFarrier: absolutely. I am just assuming it is a compiler bug and you may want to find ways how to workaround it. but i might be wrong of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `instance` name, it looks like `factory` might be a singleton, and `instance` is a static function. In that case, the value of `factory` is indeed never used, and you can instead call the function directly on the class, which is essentially what the compiler does anyway:

```
Factory::instance().Register(...);
```

Then you can remove the parameter entirely, and you'll avoid the apparent compiler bug that conflates usage of the parameter with usage of the parameter's value.

Comment: Appreciate the set of eyes on the problem!  Good solution.